# Where are the Thieves Caches in White run?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I spotted the Thieves cache symbol outside Belathors General Goods in Whiterun, but can't seem to find it, where is it, and the others in Whiterun?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you saw on his door was not the 'Thieves Cache' mark, which looks like this:
[image: Cache]

It was the "Loot Here!" mark, indicating that Belethor's shop is a good place to rob. It looks like this:
[image: Loot]

While the interior of both symbols is the same, the exterior border differs. *This matters.*

The Thieves Cache mark is only *directly on* the cache itself -  never nearby.

The Whiterun Caches, for reference, are behind Carlotta Valentia's house, South of House Grey-Mane in the City Wall, and behind the Bannered Mare.

For more on Shadowmarks, see [this answer.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37275/what-do-these-symbols-mean)

Comment: Ahh, circle vs diamond, doh!

Comment: I've edited the question in light of your answer to make it more useful... and me less of an idiot.